# Ruby RDF query - extracting simple data from Seq and Bag items

Tags: ruby, rdf

I am receiving xml-serialised RDF (as part of XMP media descriptions in case that is relevent), and processing in Ruby. I am trying to work with `rdf` gem, although happy to look at other solutions.

I have managed to load and query the most basic data, but am stuck when trying to build a query for items which contain sequences and bags.

Example XML RDF:

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf='http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#'>
 <rdf:Description rdf:about='' xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/'>
  <dc:date>
   <rdf:Seq>
    <rdf:li>2013-04-08</rdf:li>
   </rdf:Seq>
  </dc:date>
 </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

My best attempt at putting together a query:

```
require 'rdf'
require 'rdf/rdfxml'
require 'rdf/vocab/dc11'

graph = RDF::Graph.load( 'test.rdf' )

date_query = RDF::Query.new( :subject => { RDF::DC11.date => :date } )

results = date_query.execute(graph)

results.map { |result| { result.subject.to_s => result.date.inspect  } }

 => [{"test.rdf"=>"#<RDF::Node:0x3fc186b3eef8(_:g70100421177080)>"}]
```

I get the impression that my results at this stage ("query solutions"?) are a reference to the `rdf:Seq` container. But I am lost as to how to progress. For the example above, I'd expect to end up, eventually, with an array `["2013-04-08"]`.

When there is incoming data without the `rdf:Seq` and `rdf:li` containers, I am able to extract the strings I want using `RDF::Query`, following examples at http://rdf.rubyforge.org/RDF/Query.html - unfortunately I cannot find any examples of more complex queries or RDF structures processed in Ruby.

Edit: In addition, when I try to find appropriate methods to use with the `RDF::Node` object, I cannot see any way to explore any further relations it may have:

```
results[0].date.methods - Object.methods
 => [:original, :original=, :id, :id=, :node?, :anonymous?, :unlabeled?, :labeled?, :to_sym, :resource?, :constant?, :variable?, :between?, :graph?, :literal?, :statement?, :iri?, :uri?, :valid?, :invalid?, :validate!, :validate, :to_rdf, :inspect!, :type_error, :to_ntriples]
# None of the above leads AFAICS to more data in the graph
```

I know how to get the same data in xpath (well, at least provided we always get the same paths in the serialisation), but feel it is not the best query language to use in this case (it's my backup plan, however, if it turns out too complex to implement an RDF-query solution)

Comment: So far, I can get close with `@x = []; graph.query([nil, RDF::DC11.date, nil]) { |s1| graph.query( [ s1.object, RDF._1, nil] ) { |s2| @x << s2.object.to_s }  }; @x` - but I think I want something other than the `RDF._1` for a more general case. In addition, I think the first query has detached from the default context, so I'll find date strings attached to other subjects (which I don't want)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're correct when saying "my results at this stage ("query solutions"?) are a reference to the rdf:Seq container". RDF/XML is a really horrible serialisation format, instead think of the data as a graph. Here a picture of an RDF:Bag. RDF:Seq works the same and the #students in the example is analogous to the #date in your case. [image: RDF:Bag example, RDF:Seq is the same]

So to get to the date literal, you need to hop one node further in the graph. I'm not familiar with the syntax of this Ruby library, but something like:

```
require 'rdf'
require 'rdf/rdfxml'
require 'rdf/vocab/dc11'

graph = RDF::Graph.load( 'test.rdf' )

date_query = RDF::Query.new({
  :yourThing => {
    RDF::DC11.date  => :dateSeq
  },
  :dateSeq => {
      RDF.type => RDF.Seq,
      RDF._1 => :dateLiteral
  }
})

date_query.execute(graph).each do |solution|
  puts "date=#{solution.dateLiteral}"
end
```

Of course, if you expect the Seq to actually to contain multiple dates (otherwise it wouldn't make sense to have a Seq), you will have to match them with `RDF._1 => :dateLiteral1`, `RDF._2 => :dateLiteral2`, `RDF._3 => :dateLiteral3` etc.

Or for a more generic solution, match all the properties and objects on the dateSeq with:

```
:dateSeq => {
    :property => :dateLiteral
}
```

and then filter out the case where `:property` ends up being `RDF:type` while `:dateLiteral` isn't actually the date but `RDF:Seq`. Maybe the library has also a special method to get all the Seq's contents.

Comment: Thank you for the additional examples. I was hoping to find that special method on Seq or similar, none so far - but your answer has been helpful, and it's great to see a hash output containing the actual output I want inside it from a single query!

Comment: You're welcome. If that library has a special Seq method, the place to ask is probably their [mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-rdf-ruby/).